# mediafilesegmenter on CentOS?

Tags: iphone, streaming, centos, m3u

I'm working on a project where I need to batch convert files to multiple media formats, some of which will be streamed to iPhone. I'm using ffmpeg on a CentOS server, and have been using mediafilesegmenter locally to create m3u8 playlists, and it's gone swimmingly, but, in trying to get the process going on the unix server, I can't seem to find a ported/alternative version of mediafilesegmenter to use on a centOS server.

So, here's the question:

Where can I find a ported or open source version of mediafilesegmenter?

in addition, I'll need the same solution for variantplaylistcreator, although if absolutely necessary I imagine I could create a script to generate these.

Any ideas? I believe there is a tool called "segmenter" out there, but it's not in any of my repos, and I can't seem to track down a repo that has it.

Comment: You can now use ffmpeg to do this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767727/transcode-and-segment-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now segment from ffmpeg directly. see https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment

Comment: Old question, but this is now the correct answer - changed the correct answer to this one :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm working at a company with some thousands of (payment) videos.
We are using (for more than 2 years) a segmenter based on Jesse's and works great [get it here](http://pastebin.com/ULYPqNCM)

PD: Older versions of ffmpeg have relevant bugs

Answer (score 1):

Found this source : http://svn.assembla.com/svn/legend/segmenter/, which is an open source segmenter, on this article: http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/, which has some good info about streaming.

Just in case anyone else has this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Also for anyone in future - have tried both this and another OSS segmenter - and they were causing some artifacts in playback in JWPlayer flash (but not in native iDevices).
Also, according to this Zencoder post - apple segmenter is more efficient with the streams it produces: http://blog.zencoder.com/2011/12/08/announcing-the-clouds-most-efficient-http-live-streaming/

Answer (score 1):

I used Bento4 mp42hls tool to encrypt a media with the FairPlay on Linux.