# transcode and segment with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

It appears that ffmpeg now has a segmenter in it, or at least there is a command line option

-f segment

in the documentation.

Does this mean I can use ffmpeg to realtime-transcode a video into h.264 and deliver segmented IOS compatible .m3u8 streams using ffmpeg alone? if so, what would a command to transcode an arbitrary video file to a segmented h.264 aac 640 x 480 stream ios compatible stream?

Comment: If TS contain multiple programs (TV programs that captured by DVB-T), how can split it? For example I have a TS file that contain football + cooking + cartoon .How can i split this TS file to 3 mpg files?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Absolutely - you can use **-f segment** to chop video into pieces and serve it to iOS devices. ffmpeg will create segment files .ts and you can serve those with any web server.

**Working example** (with disabled sound) - ffmpeg version N-39494-g41a097a:

```
./ffmpeg -v 9 -loglevel 99 -re -i sourcefile.avi -an \
-c:v libx264 -b:v 128k -vpre ipod320 \ 
-flags -global_header -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 4 \
-segment_list test.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts stream%05d.ts
```

**Tips:**

- make sure you compile ffmpeg from most recent [git](/questions/tagged/git) repository
- compile with libx264 codec
- -map 0 is needed

How I compiled FFMPEG - with extra rtmp support to get feeds from [flash-media-server](/questions/tagged/flash-media-server)

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/pkgconfig/:../rtmpdump-2.3/librtmp"    

./configure --enable-librtmp --enable-libx264 \
--libdir='../x264/:/usr/local/lib:../rtmpdump-2.3' \
--enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-libvpx \
--disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-shared --enable-debug
```

Comment: I'm on a mac, snow leopard and I'm trying to compile this, don't need librtmp since i'm not doing RTMP streaming, any suggestions on what to download, steps I need to follow to get this working? FFmpeg how-to's seem to refer to things like libfaad which seems to not be necessary anymore.

Comment: doesn't work for me, the resulting playlist always has just the last element. [just Stream00009.ts for instance]

Comment: If TS contain multiple programs (TV programs that captured by DVB-T), how can split it? For example I have a TS file that contain football + cooking + cartoon .How can i split this TS file to 3 mpg files?

Comment: Use -map 0:X and add the streams you want to pick out. Then you can remux the streams into a new, single program (or however many programs) transport stream.

Comment: I can't find an answer to do this but with MP4/webm. Can you point me in that direction @vladman ? (I've tried different parameters in cli but couldn't make it work)

Comment: notice that if 'c:v copy' is used instead of 'c:v libx264'  then segmentation is correct if key frames are uniformply disperesed (in case of '-segment-time 4' it's expected each a key frame each 4 seconds).

Answer (score 6):

This is found in the ffmpeg documentation: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment