# download compile and install ffmpeg on Snow Leopard for HLS streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, osx-snow-leopard

In reference to this question:

[transcode and segment with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767727/transcode-and-segment-with-ffmpeg)

how can I download and install ffmpeg on my mac mini with Snow Leopard with the options listed in the answer to that question? I don't (at the moment) want to bother with RTMP support, the goal is to realtime transcode files, not live video.

Comment: @alpha You need to have Xcode installed first, that's the only way to compile things for the Mac I think.

Comment: first, yes I have xcode installed. the only reasonably good guide [link](http://jungels.net/articles/ffmpeg-howto.html) I've found says I need to install faad/faac, and seems to be out of date. I did but it appears from the errors when I try to compile that isnt needed in the current ffmpeg? I got errors about x264 and faad. I just can't seem to find a good step by step guide to download and install that actually is current and works.