# Convert H.264 to HLS in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, h.264, http-live-streaming

Using carrierwave or another file upload plugin, there should be an easy way to convert uploaded mp4 (H.264) video files to Apple HLS. You need this for *streaming* videos on mobile devices.

This way, while uploading 1 streaming video file you can support most of the browsers (every browser except Opera and FF for Linux/OSX).

It can be done with ffmpeg, is anyone working on a gem?

Answer (score 1):

How about [streamio-ffmpeg](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg)? It seems to support custom command line parameters. You could add then use parameters like from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10047372/759140

Comment: streamio-ffmpeg looks promising, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You might also give [carrierwave-video](https://github.com/rheaton/carrierwave-video) a try.  It's backed by streamio-ffmpeg and allows passing custom settings through.